# Is it possible to create an xsd that supports a parent node and child node having the same name?

Tags: xml, xsd

So before anyone tells me I shouldn't do this, I completely agree. However I have an xml DataFeed coming in from a third party. I already am reaching out to them to see if they can change it, but I figured I had better attack it from both sides.

The offending tags in the XML are as follows:

```
    <Tags>
      <TagDimension id="Topic">
        <ExternalId>Topic</ExternalId>
        <Tags>
          <Tag>
            <Label>awesome</Label>
          </Tag>
        </Tags>
      </TagDimension>
    </Tags>
```

I am by no means an XML/XSD whiz. My skills consist of running xsd.exe from the VS command line which brought me:

*C:\temp>xsd sample.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Error: There was an error processing 'sample.xml'.
  - The table (Tags) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations.*

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found "a way" although I am not sure it is a good way. It looks like an XSD file does not have any problems with recursively named nodes. It's just the xsd.exe tool. What I did was rename the inner `<Tag>` node to `<Tag2>`, which allowed me to generate the xsd file. I then opened the xsd in Visual Studio and renamed it back to `<Tag>`.

It looks like this is more a result of my dependence on tools and lack of knowledge around XSD/XML, but I would love it if someone more knowledgeable would chime in on this.